# Detect Targeted Object In An Image Uisng Python

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I have to detect the tagerted puzzle in an image using python.

**Image is below**

[Image Link Please see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuYfS.png)

Please share relevant libraries, documents etc where i can learn to solve this task.
Thanks

Comment: Please show us your code!

Comment: Have you tried googling it?